# python - decimal 'dot' to 'comma', use 2 decimals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, etl

I have this data, "VALOR" is float:

| Periodo | VALOR |
| --- | --- |
| 32021 | 1096.14 |
| 32021 | 3835.44 |
| 32021 | 2207.90 |
| 32021 | 389.10 |

**I'm trying to change decimal 'dot' to 'comma', and thats fine.**

**But I need to save the 2 decimals, and when I convert it, it desappear when the last decimal is 0.**

```py
df['VALOR'] = np.round(df['VALOR'], decimals=2).astype(str)
df['VALOR'] = df['VALOR'].str.replace('.',',')


df.head()
```

| Periodo | VALOR |
| --- | --- |
| 32021 | 1096,14 |
| 32021 | 3835,44 |
| 32021 | 2207,9 |
| 32021 | 389,1 |

**How to get the 2 decimals here?**

tried this also:

```py
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```

and this

```py
df['VALOR'] = df['VALOR'].apply(lambda x: locale.format('%.2f', x))
```

None of them worked. I need to convert the decimal to comma and maitain the 2 decimals.

Maybe some enconding would resolve? like changing my sys to UTF-8? Already tried to.. but nothing yet.

Regards,

Tanai

Comment: If you want to store it as number type, then don't do anything. The comma is a string *representation* issue. You should deal with it whenever you need to *output* in human readable format (like a string of decimal digits, or binary or hex, or whatever) -- that is *not* the concern of storing a number.

Comment: hello, thanks for reply. I need to save it as string. so we don't have converting issues between systems

Comment: I think that this is a misconception. If you store it as a number, then *that* is the guarantee you don't have conversion problems. Strings are ambiguous because of regional differences, numbers are not.

Comment: "hello, thanks for reply. I need to save it as string. so we don't have converting issues between systems " No; "so we don't have converting issues between" systems is *exactly* why you *must* save it *as a number*. Let each system *display* it as a string locally, according to its own rules. There is no conversion to do at all, unless you go out of your way to create conversions (that are sources of error).

Comment: sorry to disagree but string is immutable. this is something that I have to upload in a Federal State database and need to be in that exact format as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `apply()` method,`replace()` method and `rstrip()` method:

```
df['VALOR']=df['VALOR'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f},'.format(x))
df['VALOR'] = df['VALOR'].str.replace('.',',',regex=True)
df['VALOR']=df['VALOR'].str.rstrip(',')
```

Now If you print `df` you will get:

```
    Periodo     VALOR
0   32021       1096,14
1   32021       3835,44
2   32021       2207,90
3   32021       389,10
```